# Using js shiny events in Cypress

Tags: r, shiny, dom-events, cypress

I need to use Javascript shiny events (e.g. `shiny:recalculated`) described here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html to know when to trigger next frontend test action (without sleeps). This makes tests deterministic and reduces testing time.
However, I cannot use the event from Cypress nor from slave browser developer console.

Consider e.g. simple code taken from https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/084-single-file/app.R and modified to run app in browser

```
# Global variables can go here
n <- 200


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

After executing

```
$(document).on('shiny:recalculated', function (event) {
                if (event.target.id === "plot") {
                    alert('Output has been just refreshed')
                }
            })
```

in browser developer console and modifying input (to `201`) I get

[image: Chrome window]

However, that's not the case in case of browser runned by Cypress. Any ideas why?